# Customizing pagination info in jquery datatable is not working while table is empty

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am customizing the pagination info and it worked fine when there is some data in jquery datatable. But the same is not working when table is empty.

Customized the sInfo from "Showing _START_to_END_of_TOTAL _***entries***" to "Showing_START_to_END_of_TOTAL_".

Sample code is here. http://jsfiddle.net/inDiscover/d1fg8mrt/

## HTML

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

## JS Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var oDTOptions = {};
 oDTOptions = {"oLanguage": {"sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_"}};

    $('#myTable').dataTable(oDTOptions);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The info text for empty records is stored in `sInfoEmpty`. So

```js
"oLanguage": {
   "sInfoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0",
   "sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_"
}
```

`_START_`, `_END_` and `_TOTAL_` is not translated when using `sInfoEmpty`, it would not make sense since those values always is 0.

updated fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/d1fg8mrt/1/**

---

The above answer is targeting dataTables 1.7.5 OP is using, but works with all dataTables 1.9.x and 1.10.x versions as well. If anyone wants to use the none-hungarian naming convention in 1.10.x the equivalence is :

```js
language: {
  infoEmpty: "Showing 0 to 0 of 0",
  info: "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_"
}
```